# semantic error TS6059: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nx-workspace

I have error when i run `nx library:build`:

> semantic error TS6059: File
> '/media/user/DATA/Admin/project/libs/smart-ui/customer-info-ui/src/index.ts'
> is not under 'rootDir'
> '/media/user/DATA/Admin/project/libs/collab/workspace/src'. 'rootDir'
> is expected to contain all source files.

When check, library was imported `"@project-ui/customer-info-ui"` not use path

I'm check library and don't see `"package.json"` , i create it:

```
{
    "name": "@project-ui/customer-info-ui",
    "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

And run build, but it fail

Comment: You need to check why package name `"@project-ui/customer-info-ui"` is resolved to that path. It looks like some symbolic link. But who created that link? And why link to path outside project folder? Tell us more info.

Comment: Sorry I have no clue, I'm not familiar with `nx` tech stack.

Comment: _My leader use "nx g @nrwl/workspace:library" and set "importPath="@project-ui/customer-info-ui"
_ I check in tsconfig.base.json, it have
_ It is a library that was created to use for other libs or apps, so it is in outside project.